# HttpURLConnection send header authorization

Tags: java, android, http, restful-authentication, auth0

I am struggling to successfully send GET requests with an authorization header using HttpURLConnection. Error code 400 is returned.

I am successful with OKHttpClient but requested not to use any dependencies.

Here is my code:

```
public static String GETReqUserProfiles() throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(UrlString);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/" + "json");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Bearer " + MANAGEMENT_TOKEN);

    urlConnection.connect();

    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
    }

    String assembledOutput = "";

    BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (urlConnection.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server:\n");
    while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
        assembledOutput = assembledOutput + output;
    }

    urlConnection.disconnect();

    return assembledOutput;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Everything working -

The problem was in:

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

setDoOutput(true) : declares sending a body with the request. GET requests do not require a body, so it can be set to false or commented out. Instead this is used for POST, PATCH, PUT etc... (requests that require a body).

**Also note:**

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Does not need to be specifically declared if sending a GET request (although I left in the code for readability)

I suspect that if you include setDoOutput(true) and no request method specified, the method would default to a POST request.

Comment: put urlConnection.connect(); after setRequestProperty

Comment: Hi Abhay, thank you, I inclucded the connect and still returns 400 :(

Comment: @AbhayBohra Why? It is executed automatically.

Comment: The fact that `setDoOutput(true)` sets the request method to POST is clearly stated in the Javadoc.